# Read files with EnumerateFiles and multiple filter (file extensions)

Tags: c#, filesystems

I need to load dynamically file from folder and sub folders.

I use this code to load my files:

```
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".txt") || s.EndsWith(".xml") || s.EndsWith(".log") || s.EndsWith(".csv"))
        .ToList();
```

It is slow but it is better than all other method I already tried.

Now I would like to change this line to have something dynamic so that I can filter my extensions

```
.Where(s => s.EndsWith(".txt") || s.EndsWith(".xml") || s.EndsWith(".log") || s.EndsWith(".csv"))
```

So, first step I replace my line with this:

```
filter.Split('|').ToList().ForEach(y =>
{
    files.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(s => s.EndsWith(y))
        .ToList());
});
```

But then I can also remove the Where instruction and use the filter from EnumerateFiles(). Yes ok sure. But the problem is also by doing this i do multiple call to EnumerateFiles() and this is even more slower.

What can I do?

Is this better

```
var allFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var files = new List<string>();

filter.Split('|').ToList().ForEach(y =>
{
    files.AddRange(allFiles.Where(s => s.EndsWith(y)).ToList());
});
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do the following

```
var extensions = filter.Split('|').ToHashSet(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s)))
    .ToList();
```

Edit:

FYI your `Is this better` code is 100% the same as your previous code.
`IEnumerable` is lazy and will only be exectued when used, so declaring  `var allFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);` outside of the loop makes no difference.

See here a demonstration:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/UZj8lr

Comment: This is why I call ToList() :-S

Comment: @BastienVandamme - only for the end result, but not for allFiles - allFiles will be parsed over and over again :-S, maybe re-read my answer since I explicitly mention where you don’t call .tolist and why your both code parts are identically, of you have questions hit me